# windows 2003 - Backup File server

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, file-server

Witch is the way to backup file server including directory structure and file permissions?

For now, I'm backing up on DVD the files directly, but I want to backup also the Security ACL, It is possible?

Comment: You can look at these other questions: http://serverfault.com/questions/10084/looking-for-alternative-to-symantec-backup-exec-12-5, http://serverfault.com/questions/163372/backups-for-online-businesses-better-external-hard-drives-or-tape-drives, http://serverfault.com/questions/119120/how-to-use-a-volume-shadow-copy-to-make-backups, http://serverfault.com/questions/160484/windows-linux-backup-software-with-bare-metal-recovery

Comment: Thank's, I was expecting a native windows server solution, but seems it's not available

Comment: Ah, then what you're looking for is NTBackup, which is native to 2003 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment above, it sounds like you're going to need to use NTBackup.  It's native to Server 2003.  See this [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781353%28WS.10%29.aspx) article on backing up the system state.  A quick Google search yields [results](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814583) on setting up jobs using command line parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't kwon that could be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a cheap solution by any means, Acronis True Image Server does a good job of backing up file systems and preserving ACL information on Windows machines.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, this is very easy to do with tools such as rsync.

On Windows, your best bet is probably to purchase a commercial backup solution such as Norton Ghost.

Comment: Norton is geared more for desktop backup/recovery.  If you want to stay within the Symantec line, he needs to consider NetBackup or Backup Exec.